# CKEditor not displaying image data

Tags: javascript, html, image, ckeditor

It's quite peculiar. My html string has 2 images in it - 2 separate image tags. A triangle followed by a circle. The image data is 64-bit encoded data. The html source for the images look like this:

```
<p>
<img alt="dac84c31850f292e0bb60901680b27b7.png" src="data:image/png;  base64, encoded-image-data here></p>
```

If I paste the html source for any one of the images, CKEDitor displays is correctly. If I paste in the html with both images, only the circle is displayed. Where did the triangle go? Did it get overwritten? Is there something I need to set in Javascript before I upload the html into CKEditor. At present here's what I do:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['myinstance'].setData(data['question']);
```

where data['question'] contains the html source.

In reading this forum, looks like there are a lot of image display problems with CKEditor - but this one has me stumped.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Mmiz

Comment: Do you have an example you could show? Or a pastebin (or similar) of the actual image data so we could test with our installations as well? Interesting situation.

Comment: I had wanted to paste in the image data but I don't think this editor likes it. Is there somewhere else I could post it? It's not that large.

Comment: Maybe in http://pastebin.com/ ?

Comment: gotcha! Did not know that's what you'd meant. Sorry. I'll do it right away. Done - titled: CKEditor:Image Issue Example. I'd be very interested to know if you are able to successfully have CKEditor display both the images. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is a little corrupt, I think that's breaking CKEditor in this interesting way. Look at your image data closely. The image tags end with this:

```
...AAElFTkSuQmCC"  21px; height: 24px;">
```

That is not a valid tag (the style attribute is broken). Try something like this for both images and it works

```
...AAElFTkSuQmCC" style="height:24px; width:18px" />
```

Comment: Err my height and width values are a little wrong but you get the idea

Comment: http://pastebin.com/edV6ByKm Here's the pastebin for the original if anyone else is interested by the way. And http://pastebin.com/uKs7Wwmn here is my proposed solution.

Comment: oh thank you thank you! It does, indeed, work! Just goes to show, debugging-when-i-should-have-known-better-and-gone-to-bed is not recommended. Thank you again! Much obliged.